# TFS Bug reassignment behaviour

Tags: tfs

This is likely by design for big teams with proper QA departments, but we are only 3 devs and do round robin QA on each others work.

The problem is say person A creates a bug, and assign it to person B, and the person B resolves the bug, TFS reassigns the bug to the creator.

This makes keeping track of your own fixed bugs nigh impossible.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Thanks

leppie

Comment: Which process template are you using?

Comment: Actually, I dont know, I never setup the server.

Comment: It is bound to be the 'agile coding olympics' one, will confirm tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make changes like this is with the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).  Among many other things, it will add a "Process Editor" area under your Tools menu in VS.  Use the "open WIT from server" feature to download the work item type that's bothering you, make the changes you want (under the Workflow tab in your case), then run "import WIT" to upload it back to the server.

The complete XML specification for work item types is documented on MSDN, but as usual it's quite dense.  Here's a [series of blog posts](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2009_05_01_archive.html) that walks you through the possibilities.

Comment: Awesome dude! Worked like a charm, just had to delete 1 field  :)